# No errors show, but Chrome.Storage.Sync. Get is not receiving what I set in Chrome.Storage.Sync.Set

Tags: javascript, java, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to use the options part of my extension as a way for users to write websites that will later be used in the background script to create new tabs of those websites. There are no errors, but when I try to run the extension none of the websites they put in actually open. I am not sure if this is a problem with the way I coded the chrome.storage.sync.set API or the way I coded the chrome.storag.sync.get API or something completely different.

Here is my options.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <script src="options.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Choose Website</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Choose Websites Here</h1>
    <h4> <i>Please Put the full URL</i></h4>
    <h4><i>Example: "https://www.google.com"</i></h4>
    <h2>Website #1: <input type="text" id="website1"></h2>
    <h2>Website #2: <input type="text" id="website2"></h2>
    <h2>Website #3: <input type="text" id="website3"></h2>
    <button type="button" name="Save Changes" id="savechanges">Save Changes</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

options.js

```
function WebsiteChoosing (){
  $('#savechanges').click(function(){
    var website1 = $('#website1').val();
    var website2 = $('#website2').val();
    var website3 = $('#website3').val
    if(website1){
      chrome.storage.sync.set({'website1' : website1})
    }
    if(website2){
      chrome.storage.sync.set({'website1' : website1})
    }
    if(website3){
      chrome.storage.sync.set({'website1' : website1})
  }
})

  };
```

backround.js (only relevant)

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(buttonClicked)

function buttonClicked () {

chrome.storage.sync.get(['website1', 'website2', 'website3'], data => {
  if (data.website1) chrome.tabs.create({url: data.website1});
  if (data.website2) chrome.tabs.create({url: data.website2});
  if (data.website3) chrome.tabs.create({url: data.website3});
});
```

Manifest.json (only relevant)

```
 "background" : {
      "scripts" : ["background.js"]
  },

  "options_page": "options.html",
  "permissions": [

  "history",
  "storage",
  "activeTab",
  "tabs"
```

Comment: Don't use `<input type="Submit"`, use `<button>` instead. Submitting a form on an extension page simply reloads it like it would on pressing Ctrl-R so everything is lost. Also you've missed `#` in `$('#savechanges')`.

Comment: I made those changes but the problem still persists, I added some of my manifest.json to my original comment in case there was something wrong there.

Comment: The background script runs in a hidden background page. It's like a hidden tab that has its own life cycle: it runs when the extension is loaded, installed, re-enabled, or when resumed in case the background script was declared with "persistent":false. Depending on when you want to open those tabs, you either don't need a background script at all or you need to put there a `chrome` event listener, inside of which you'll create the tabs.

Comment: I do have a listener in my code and I am pretty much positive that works because the other things in my code that are supposed to happen when the button is pressed, still happen. I added the listener into my post anyway in case there is somehow something wrong with it.

Comment: Re-read your code in WebsiteChoosing: you're saving the same website1.

Comment: Sorry I am kind of confused on what you mean by that. Could you give me an example on how to fix it. Thank You!

Comment: This is really something that you need to do yourself: https://puu.sh/Gbdwf/4f067384f0.png

Comment: Oh thank you I do not know how I did not notice that. The code still does not work though, I am sure that it is something stupid that I did. Is there anything else I did that could cause this problem, or anyway I can test and find out where the problem is? Thank you in advance

Comment: To have browserAction.onClicked work, you need `"browser_action": {}` in manifest.json (important: don't specify default_popup there!)

Comment: I have Browser action in the manifest, I know clicking the button is working because there are other things the extension does that is working, only the chrome.storage.sync does not work.

Comment: It's hard to help without being sure that your question includes a **real** [MCVE](/help/mcve). For example, options.js only declares WebsiteChoosing function but never calls it. The first thing that you need to learn is how to use devtools to debug the code. Then you'll solve all such problems in a matter of seconds.